# Driver can not be resolved. When running it on eclipse with selenium web driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, selenium-ide

Bellow is the code where it is running on selenium web driver. And noting to say more about code. It
has some error in driver.get section and as well as the next section.
package practice;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");


    WebDriver objname= new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.mortgagecalculator.org/");

    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("homeval")).sendKeys("5000");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

When running this code i am getting the error. So any suggestion on the above code.
I run the above code but the error is getting on the line and any of the thing which is not in proper
format.

Please check below image for more clarification. Thanks

[image: image_link]

Comment: In your example, the variable for the "Selenium WebDrvier" is named "objname" (Line 14)  and not driver. So change the variable name from "driver" to "objname" or vice versa

Comment: Please Change: WebDriver objname= new ChromeDriver(); to WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have to import selenium packages

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

To resolve this do mouse over "driver" and import class

Comment: You should import selenium jar files into your project

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Webdriver reference variable name as "objname" and then in the below code you are trying to use "driver" but there is no reference variable present your project with the name as "driver". So either create the Webdriver driver; reference variable or just change the existing "objname" to "driver"